# How to call method from different class in MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to call a method from 'Check.cs' in MainWindow.

I've tried to set instance.

```
Check ch = new Check();

class Check 
{
    public static string IsOpen(string text)
    {
       // My logic

    }
}
```

I expected to be able to set instance, but whenever I want to I can't find it, also I'm not able to set it.

Comment: You made IsOpen static so it would just be Check.IsOpen...

Comment: But that doesnt work in WPF , i've tried already.

Comment: @Gameines BugFinder is correct, you do not need to create an instance of Check, simply call the static method directly. This article explains what a static method is: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/static-methods-in-C-Sharp/

What error are you getting? Maybe you can post the code from MainWindow so we can see how you're calling it?

Comment: @GameIns it works. The stack doesn't matter (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET Core MVC) this is how C# works.

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy It works now. Code : ``var isPalindrome = Check.IsPalindrome(text);`` I forgot the using above.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and my method wasn't public that was the secon reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make your class `public`. Now you should get errors trying to create instance of that class.

Then, you need to add reference to library (.dll) that this is compiled to, unless this is in the same project.

Also, you need `using` directive to point to a namespace, where `Check` class is located.

Finally, as already said, your method is static, so you don't need to create instance to call this method. Although it can be called on an instance as well. So both ways are valid:

```
 var ch = new Check();
 ch.IsOpen();
 Check.IsOpen();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did almost the same. ``var isPalindrome = Check.IsPalindrome(text);`` I will accept your answer, but I need to wait a bit.

Comment: please clarify, in which .NET version "it can be called on an instance as well"; `Member 'Check.IsOpen()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead` is more likely outcome